# A countable set contained in $[0,1]$ with no limit points?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I am asked to determine if such a set even exists, and proof for my answer. Thinking about it intuitively, I believe it cannot exist. But I need help explaining why. Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you know the Bolzano-Weierstrass Theorem?

Comment: Yes. So since it is contained in $[0,1]$, create a sequence of the countable set, and use the B-W Thm to show that it must have a subsequence that converges?

Comment: By the way, the word "countable" is ambiguous. It could mean countably infinite, or it could include finite things as well.

Comment: I'd like to revisit this question. The references to Bolzano-Weierstrass do not seem to conclusive to me, as we need to prove that $ x_n \rightarrow x $ *with the stipulation* $ x_n \neq x , \forall n $. That's using the definition of limit point in Abbott.

Comment: @Preston: Once you have such a sequence, you can pick a subsequence $y_n$ such that $y_n \neq x$ for each $x$ as follows: Letting $d$ be least of the distances from $x$ to $0$ and $1,$ consider these disjoint open "rings" about $x,$ ordered by decreasing thickness -- $(x-d+d/2,\;x+d-d/2)$ and $(x-d+d/2+d/4,\;x+d-d/2-d/4)$ and $(x-d+d/2+d/4+d/8,\;x+d-d/2-d/4-d/8)$ and so on. **(continued)**

Comment: Let $y_1$ be from the original sequence that belongs to the first ring having at least one term of the original sequence in that ring, let $y_2$ be from the original sequence that belongs to the next ring having at least one term of the original sequence in that ring, and so on. Not only do we have $y_n \rightarrow x$ with each $y_n \neq x$ (because none of the rings that we're picking the points from contains $x),$ but we additionally have the property that no two terms of this new sequence are the same (because the rings are pairwise disjoint). (A handwritten diagram will help.)

Comment: Incidentally, if my use of "ring" is confusing for the open sets dealt with (and it occurs to me it would be), then think of the analogous situation in which the main set is a (closed and bounded) region in the plane, such as $[0,1]\times[0,1].$

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** Divide the $[0,1]$ into two pieces of equal size; necessarily at least one piece will have infinitely many points. Repeat this process and observe that there must necessarily be a limit point in $[0,1]$.

Answer (score 2):

You say countable. If you allow finite it's trivial. If you meant infinite, it's impossible. Bolzano's theorem states that every sequence in a compact metric space has a convergent subsequence, which limit is an acummulation point. Every infinitr countable set in $[0,1]$ contains a sequence. So it remain you study Bolzano's theorem.